# How do you develop a flight route view using HERE Maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I wanted to develop a map component, where a user can create a route including airports. If the user selects two airports, then the screen should automatically show the air distance and duration between the two, in a map.

But, when I checked the docs, I'm seeing that HERE Maps does not even have 'flight' as a transport mode. Is this true? Can HERE Maps only work with road-based routes and no flight mode at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that we are not supporting 'flight' as a transport mode. But you can show the path by drawing geodesic polyline as shown in below example.

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/geodesic_polyline

Comment: Alright, thank you. That is exactly what we had in mind, as the alternative solution. But, is there a way to get the air distance/duration for the route?

Comment: Currently we are not supporting such features.